# select ms-access from PHP is not up to date

Tags: php, ms-access

I select ms-access from another PC using PHP. when there is a change in ms-access, data in my PHP select are not latest. Why did it happen. this is my connection :

```
<?php
    $connStr = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=\\\\192.168.130.21\db_finger\TJ_Main_Data.mdb;";
    $con = odbc_connect($connStr,"sa","everyday");
    if($con>1) {
        echo "";
    } 
    else { 
        echo "Koneksi ke database Finger gagal";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `write` privileges on that file ?

Comment: @hexYeah no. just read only.. btw i adding data not from php

Comment: Do you mean you could connect to the database and fetch some data from a table, but the data are not latest?

Comment: @Phil Yes, right. sorry if my language is hard to understand

Comment: @sate wedos, Your description is clear. I just can't imagine what strange situation you are facing :)

Comment: Write access is required when reading from an Access file. This is because of the way Access works with record locks. Reading from the file requires setting a read lock, and that requires write privileges. Usually, accessing read-only files generates an error.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth is this the last resort? I do not want to take risks by changing permissions